# SwiftUI's Table: can you disable content diffing to improve performance?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUIs 'Table' to display large arrays (> 100.000) but experiencing nearly O(n²) performance penalty on updates of the array. In the following example (macOS) the table is drawn instantly on app start, but replacing the contents of the 'items' array takes several seconds, even if the new array is just empty:

```
struct TableTest: View {
    
    @State private var items: [Person] = (0..<500000).map { _ in Person() }

    var body: some View {
        Table(items) {
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Age") { person in Text(String(person.age)) }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem() {
                Button("Clear") {
                    items = []
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Person: Identifiable {

        let id = UUID()
        let name: String = ["Olivia", "Elijah", "Leilani", "Gabriel", "Eleanor", "Sebastian", "Zoey", "Muhammad"].randomElement()!
        let age: Int = Int.random(in: 18...110)
    }
}
```

An array size of 1.000.000 items takes >30s to update.

Profiling the app suggests that the heavy lifting happens in

```
v AppKitTableCoordinator.updateTableView(_:from:to:)
  > ListBatchUpdates.computeMoves<A>(from:to:)
  > ListBatchUpdates.computeRemovesAndInserts<A>(from:to:)
```

so I assume the delay is caused by automatic diffing of the old and new array. I can see that Table accesses each and every of my 500.000 'Person' structs individually asking their 'id' which also suggests that it's diffing the arrays.

It would be great to switch that off. I tried using the .id(UUID()) modifier on the Table to force SwiftUI into treating each Table struct as brand new, but that didn't change anything.

The only workaround I see is using 'NSViewRepresentable' to display an 'NSTableView' but I'd prefer to use 'Table'.

So my question: is there a way to convince SwiftUI to refrain from diffing?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with a table with around 10,0000 rows. Sorting them happens pretty quickly in the background object, but once the sort completes (2ms) the table takes many seconds to update. using .id(UUID()) or id on the sort order to force the view to rebuild from start is also instant with the only downside is that view columns that users have resized get reset back to the default values. Obviously as the view is being rebuilt from new with a new identity. Would be nice to preserve view identity and force a complete update/rebuild rather than differencing.